# how can i make my linux service trigger my signal?

Tags: c++, linux, service

I have made my first linux service with C++.

```
pid_t pid, sid;

pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (pid>0) {
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

umask(0);

sid = setsid();
if (sid < 0) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

close(STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);

while (1) {
    ????????
    //sleep(10);
}

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

What it would do is to wait for my signal and when it receives it to do some tasks and then again wait for my next signal.

I would send my signal (or whatever) somehow from within my c++ app that runs on same machine. Seems like a mechanism of semaphore between two apps. But in this case one is a linux service, and I do not know how the service could wait my signal.

How could I achieve this? What are my alternatives?

Thanks.

**Note:** The word "signal" caused to confusion. I didn't intend to use that word as technically. I just mean that I need to talk to my linux service from within my cpp app.

**NOTE 2:** Using signal is not useful because in its handler almost doing any thing is unsafe, whereas I need to do lots of things. (I dont know if I could start a thread, at least!)

Comment: What do you mean by "signal"? What is your "server" supposed to be doing? Communication between two processes on the same system is just normal [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), that one process runs in the background doesn't matter.

Comment: [`sigwait`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sigwait), if you really meant signals

Comment: I dont mean any thing especially. Just I want to communicate to my linux service from within my cpp app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found the right keywords to google what I needed to know.
Here are the alternative ways to communicate between different processes:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an handler that takes care of SIGHUP and SIGTERM, your program could send these signals using `kill -9 processid` or `kill -HUP processid` of course there is a few other signals you could use for this purpose check `man signal`

```
void handler (int signal_number){
    //action
    exit(1);
}
```

And in the main program

```
struct sigaction act;
struct sigaction act2;
memset (&act, 0, sizeof (act));
memset (&act2, 0, sizeof (act2));

act.sa_handler = handler;
act2.sa_handler = handler;
if (sigaction (SIGHUP, &act, NULL) < 0) {
    perror ("sigaction");
}

if (sigaction (SIGTERM, &act, NULL) < 0) {
    perror ("sigaction");
}

//wait here for ever or do something.
```

Comment: Within handle doing any thing is safe? Could I start a long action? Or this way is special and we have limits?
For example here tells that printf is not safe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigaction

Comment: check `man signal` or [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for a complete chapter of safe-signal actions.

Comment: @MertKoksal I you think that my answer is correct I would be happy if you mark the answer as correct

Comment: your answer was useful. Sure I'll give uppoint. Thank you much. However as I stated later more clearly my aim was to know alternatives to communicate from my cpp app to service.